# Cannot find package GLFW using CMake

Tags: opengl, cmake, glfw

**My project structure looks like this:**

- CMakeLists.txt
- deps

  - glew
  - glfw
- include
- src

  - ...
  - graphics

    - ...
    - CMakeLists.txt

*Two CMakeLists.txt files that deserve attention:*

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(noam_engine)

find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(NE_LIBRARIES common math graphics)

FOREACH(lib ${NE_LIBRARIES})
    add_subdirectory(src/${lib})
ENDFOREACH(lib)

add_executable(noam_engine src/main.cpp)

if(OPENGL_FOUND AND GLEW_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(noam_engine PUBLIC include ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(noam_engine ${NE_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

**src/graphics/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

file(GLOB SRC "*.cpp")
add_library(graphics ${SRC})

if(OPENGL_FOUND AND GLEW_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(graphics PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(graphics ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} ${GLFW3_LIBRARY} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
    message(STATUS "GLFW and GLEW successfully linked")
    message(STATUS ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
    message(STATUS ${GLFW3_LIBRARY})
    message(STATUS ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
else()
    message(STATUS "Cannot find GL libraries")
endif()
```

In a few words I want to create a bunch of static libraries of the engine, in particular, link `graphics` library with GL's, and finally link all of them with the executable in a root CMakeLists.txt.

But I noticed that **${GLFW3_LIBRARY}** is empty and I got a linker error, for example, when I call **glfwInit()**. I followed the guide during building and installation of GLFW

```
cmake .
make
make install
```

I believe headers and libraries are in /usr/local/*, but apparently CMake cannot find them or maybe I did something wrong.

The only hypothesis I have is that find_package doesn't know about glfw3Config.cmake which is in deps/glfw/*

Comment: Call for `find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)` has been succeed, but result of this call depends on the script used by it. If you have `Findglfw3.cmake` script, then "documentation" of the script is contained in its beginning lines. If you have `glfw2Config.cmake` script which looks like [given one](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/glfw3Config.cmake.in), then result of `find_package` call is a `glfw` target, with which you need to link your library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took the script from https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindGLFW3.cmake and put it into cmake folder. Then in CMakeLists.txt I added

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
```

Now everything works properly

Thanks @Tsyvarev

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! It’s amazing how much trouble this was. The question comes up all over—even on glfw’s own forums—but for no apparent reason they don’t include it, nor does CMake.       (I’ll just add: the ge_macros at the bottom aren’t necessary, and if it’s not already there you need to set CMAKE_MODULES_PATH in your CMakeLists.txt.)